# laravel 5.4 how to write select from multi table query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How am using laravel 5.4,

to write sql query to get data from multiple tables for below query

```
select l.party_id,l.container_id,p.party_name from 
`tbl_container_lease` l, `tbl_partys` p 
where l.`party_id` = p.`id` and l.`user_id` = 5
```

Now am using this

```
Containerlease::whereHas('getpartys',function($q){})
->where('user_id','=',$user_id)
->get();
```

but it is getting too confuse to use

is there any better alternative to use this query by using model..

Comment: `,function($q){}` can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to join the tables to do this.

```
Containerlease::join('tbl_partys', 'tbl_partys.id', '=', 'tbl_container_lease.party_id')
    ->where('tbl_container_lease.user_id', 5)
    ->select('tbl_partys.*', 'tbl_container_lease.*');
    ->get();
```

However, an even better way would be to create relations if you are using Eloquent. The documentation for this can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, since you're in laravel after all, to make use of laravel relationships.

Make sure you have a party model:

```
php artisan make:model Party
```

Assuming **one lease has one party**, In your container lease model add:

```
public function party(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Party', 'id', 'party_id');
}
```

Then access your model

```
ContainerLease::with('party')->where('user_id', '=', 5)->get();
```